# If a gold coin is found, what is the probability that the second box was chosen?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> **Question:**
> *There are three identicalboxes, each provides with two drawers. In the first, each drawer contains a gold coin, in the third, each drawer contains a silver coin and in the second, one drawer contains a gold and the other a silver coin. A box is selected at random and one of the drawers is opened.  If a gold coin is found, what is the probabilitythat the box chosen is the second one?*

---

**My try:**
Let, $P(A)\Rightarrow$ Probability of choosing first box
$P(B)\Rightarrow$ Probability of choosing second box
$P(C)\Rightarrow$ Probability of choosing third box
$G\Rightarrow$ is the event of finding a gold coin
$S\Rightarrow$ is the event of finding a silver coin
Now, $P(A)= P(B)= P(C) = \frac 13$
And we have to find $P(B \mid G)$.
Now, according to the formula,
$$P(B \mid G) = \frac{P(B \cap G)}{P(G)}$$
But, I can't understand how to find $P(G)$ and $P(B \cap G)$. Please help.

Comment: Since you've written out the formula, why don't you try finding the two probabilities on the right hand side? Can you interpret them? If so, what difficulty have you met in calculating these two? Putting these in your question helps people write up better answers.

Comment: There are six total drawers. One of the drawers has a gold coin and is in the second box. Three of the drawers have gold coins. This should be enough to define $P(G)$ and $P(B \cap G)$ using successes/(total possible outcomes).

Comment: @DavidDiaz are you telling that $P(G)= \frac 36 = \frac 12$ and $P(B \cap G)= \frac 12$?

Comment: That would be weird because the probability of Box 2 given a gold coin is less than one. How did you get your probabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that requires you to know Bayes' theorem on conditional probability. It is just basically an extension of what you have written out. What it says is,
$$\ P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$ You can try it to prove it yourself, from what you have written itself.

Now, to the problem, it asks us to find the probability that the second chest is selected given that a gold coin is obtained. So, we are asked to find $\ P(B|G)$. From Bayes' theorem, it is,
$$\ P(B|G)=\frac{P(G|B)P(B)}{P(G)}$$
Can you proceed?

Anyway, I continue.
We write it using Bayes' form because we can find out each term in the RHS. Now,
$$\ \frac{P(G|B)P(B)}{P(G)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{3}+1 \cdot \frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{3}$$
I hope the answer is correct and hope it helps!

Comment: Yes the answer is absolutely correct and it helped me a lot. Thank you very much